# Running zero blocks in cuda

Tags: cuda

I have a loop like this:

```
while ( ... ) {
    ...
    kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>( ... );
}
```

and in some iterations `blocks` or `threads` have value `0`. When I use this my code runs. My question is if this is considered bad practice, and if there are any other bad side effects.

Comment: I don't think it will have an overhead on the program since the kernel will simply not launch if you specify 0 number of threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's bad practice because it will interfere with [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).

If you do proper error checking, your kernel launches that have all-zero values for block or grid dimensions will throw an error.

It's preferable to write error free programs for a variety of reasons.

Instead, include a test for these cases and skip the kernel launch when your dimensions are zero.  The small overhead in C-code to do this will be more than offset by the reduced API overhead by not making the spurious kernel launch request.

Comment: Indeed, I get `invalid configuration argument` during kernel launch when one of the grid or block sizes is 0, but is this documented somewhere or is this post the only place to find this info?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried zero block kernel invocation by simply writing following empty kernel.

File:

```
#include<stdio.h>

__global__ void fg()
{

} 
int main()
{   
 fg<<<0,1>>>();
}
```

What I noticed was the only side effect was in terms of the time required for execution.

Run time :

real 0m0.242s,
   user 0m0.004s,
   sys  0m0.148s.

When I run the same file with kernel invocation commented the side effect of overhead in time decreases.

Run time:

real 0m0.003s,
   user 0m0.000s,
   sys  0m0.000s.

This side effect arises due to the kernel invocation over head for zero blocks.